# Python - Way to trap SIGTERM caught by a third party module and propagate to script

Tags: python, python-2.7, signals

I'm running a simple Python script that reads from a Kafka stream which uses a underlying library(call it `libidb`) written in C. The  script reads from this stream continuously.

For a particular debug purpose I need to dump a dictionary in a JSON format when the script terminates. I've used the `signal` module to trap `SIGINT`, `SIGTERM` from the script and defined a function to invoke on these signals to dump the output. But the problem is my script spends most of the time using the library (for read/write) I was referring to which ends up catching the signal and it is *not* propagated to the script. So the result is my signal handlers are not made use here. How do I make sure the caught signal is propagated to the interpreter and then the corresponding signal handler is invoked.

Note that `idb` is internal module which is not available in standard Python packages.

```
import signal
import json
import idb

def dump_dict_to_JSON():
    __location__ = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.dirname(__file__)))
    f = open(os.path.join(__location__, 'dict_map'), 'w');
    f.write(json.dumps(my_dict))
    f.close()



def idb_handler():
    print('I can do whatever with the message from stream')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, dump_dict_to_JSON)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, dump_dict_to_JSON)

    db_consumer = idb.AsyncConsumer(istream, idb_handler)
```

I'm using `Python 2.7.5` on Centos 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one signal handler per signal in the kernel. Basically it means the last installed one sees the interrupt.

Depending on signal type and other circumstances a handler may be designed to call the previously installed handler in a daisy-chain matter.

This is obviously not the case in the mentioned library.

As a workaround, you should install your handler AFTER the library is initialized and probably call their handler when the JSON is dumped.